# How to avoid a DestinationAccessException when sending a POST request to an OData service using SAP Cloud SDK version 3.2.0

Tags: java, odata, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk

I'm developing a Java application that uses SAP Cloud SDK version 3.2.0. I've an endpoint that handles a request  asynchronously using queueCallable of ResilienceDecorator; through this service, Business Partners (BP) are created.  I'm doing stress tests using SoapUI, sometimes when sending multiple requests, for example, 50 requests, a  DestinationAccessException is generated. I don't know what is the cause of this problem, could someone help me find a solution?

Sometimes the following message is displayed:

> DestinationAccessException:
>   com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.exception.DestinationAccessException:
>   javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:
>   org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory]

Other times the following message is displayed:

> DestinationAccessException: No destination for name
>   'ErpQueryEndpoint' could be found in any of the registered loaders.

This is my class AccountController:

```
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    AccountBF accountBF;

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bp/create/extended", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> createBpExtended(@RequestBody BpCreateBasicRequest bpCreateRequest) throws IOException {

        Object bpCreateBasicResponse = accountBF.bpCreateExtended(bpCreateRequest);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(bpCreateBasicResponse);
    }
}
```

This is my class AccountBFimpl:

```
public class AccountBFimpl implements AccountBF {

    private ResilienceConfiguration conf;

    ...

    public Object executeAsyncCall(BpCreateBasicRequest bpCreateRequest) {

        LogMessage logMessage = new LogMessage();

        ...

        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;

        try {

            ODataCreateRequestImpl createRequest = new ODataCreateRequestImpl("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZAS_BP_CREATION_SRV",
            "BP_DATASet", bodyAsMap, null, null, null, headersAsMap, null, false, null, null, false);

            createRequest.execute("ErpQueryEndpoint");
            jsonResponse = new JSONObject();

        } catch (DestinationAccessException e ) {
            System.out.println("DestinationAccessException: "+e.getMessage());
            logMessage.setMessageContent("Creating the BP: " + bpCreateRequest.getNumeroId() + ". " +
            " DestinationAccessException: "+e.getMessage());
            writeMessageContent(logMessage);
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException e ) {
            System.out.println("HttpServerErrorException: " + e.getMessage());
            logMessage.setMessageContent("Creating the BP: " + bpCreateRequest.getNumeroId() + ". " +
            " HttpServerErrorException: "+e.getMessage());
            writeMessageContent(logMessage);
        } catch (Exception e ) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            logMessage.setMessageContent("Creating the BP: " + bpCreateRequest.getNumeroId() + ". " +
            " Exception: "+e.getMessage());
            writeMessageContent(logMessage);
        }

        ...

        return jsonResponse;
    }

    public Object bpCreateExtended(BpCreateBasicRequest bpCreateRequest) throws IOException {

        LogMessage logMessage = new LogMessage();
        logMessage.setMessageContent("Creating the BP: " + bpCreateRequest.getNumeroId() + ". " + "Entering the" +
        " bpCreateExtended method");
        writeMessageContent(logMessage);

        this.conf = ResilienceConfiguration.of(AccountBFimpl.class);
        Object response = null;

        CompletableFuture<Object> futureFirstStep = ResilienceDecorator.queueCallable(() ->
                executeAsyncCall(bpCreateRequest), conf);

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logMessage.setMessageContent("Creating the BP: " + bpCreateRequest.getNumeroId() + ". " +
            " InterruptedException in sleep - bpCreateExtended: "+e.getMessage());
            writeMessageContent(logMessage);
        }

        logMessage.setMessageContent("After create the BP: " + bpCreateRequest.getNumeroId() + ". " + "Leaving the" +
        " bpCreateExtended method");
        writeMessageContent(logMessage);

        return (JSONObject) response;
    }
}
```

This is the content of my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.atlantida.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>account</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>atlantida</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <springframework.version>5.1.8.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <jackson-version>2.9.2</jackson-version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>

        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>

        <!-- if you are behind a proxy use the following two properties to configure your proxy. Default: None -->
        <proxy.host />
        <proxy.port />
        <non.proxy.hosts />

        <!-- Properties that are related to the SAP Cloud Platform. -->
        <scp.sdkVersion>1.44.12</scp.sdkVersion>

        <!-- this is the location of your local SAP CP Neo runtime -->
        <scp.sdkInstallPath>${project.basedir}/scp/sdk-${scp.sdkVersion}</scp.sdkInstallPath>
        <scp.sdkLocalServerContentPath>${project.basedir}/localServerContent</scp.sdkLocalServerContentPath>
        <scp.sdkErpEndpoint>${scp.sdkInstallPath}/server/config_master/service.destinations/destinations/ErpQueryEndpoint</scp.sdkErpEndpoint>

        <scp.sdkSymbolicLink>${project.basedir}/scp/sdk</scp.sdkSymbolicLink>
        <scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>.sh</scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>
        <scp.sdkNeoCmd>${scp.sdkInstallPath}/tools/neo${scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension}</scp.sdkNeoCmd>
        <scp.sdkLocalServer>${scp.sdkInstallPath}/server</scp.sdkLocalServer>

        <scp.skipInstallSdk>false</scp.skipInstallSdk>
        <scp.skipDeploy>false</scp.skipDeploy>
        <scp.skipPutDestination>false</scp.skipPutDestination>
        <scp.skipRestart>false</scp.skipRestart>
        <scp.skipRollingUpdate>true</scp.skipRollingUpdate>

        <scp.vmArguments />
        <scp.vmSize>lite</scp.vmSize>
        <scp.vmMinProcesses>1</scp.vmMinProcesses>
        <scp.vmMaxProcesses>1</scp.vmMaxProcesses>

        <scp.app />
        <scp.host />
        <scp.account />
        <scp.username />
        <scp.password />

        <!-- Required for SAP CP user session management and audit logging. -->
        <scp.warImportPackage>com.sap.security.auth.service,com.sap.security.um.service.api,com.sap.core.service.auditlog.impl,com.sap.cloud.auditlog,com.sap.cloud.auditlog.exception,com.sap.cloud.auditlog.extension</scp.warImportPackage>

        <!-- Defines whether the deployment is productive or not. -->
        <productive />
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bridge logging from JCL to SLF4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>scp-neo</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.servicesdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>odatav2-connectivity-sdk3</artifactId>
            <version>1.36.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>security-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo-javaee7-wp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>atlantida</finalName>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>SAP Cloud SDK Project Structure Checks</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <requireMavenVersion>
                                        <version>3.5</version>
                                    </requireMavenVersion>
                                    <requireJavaVersion>
                                        <version>${java.version}</version>
                                    </requireJavaVersion>
                                    <reactorModuleConvergence />
                                </rules>
                                <fail>true</fail>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                        <archive>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                                <Import-Package>${scp.warImportPackage}</Import-Package>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                        <webResources>
                            <resources>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resources>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
                                <artifactId>neo-javaee7-wp-sdk</artifactId>
                                <version>${scp.sdkVersion}</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${scp.sdkInstallPath}</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Plugin for deployment to SAP Cloud Platform Neo. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo-javaee7-wp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${scp.sdkVersion}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipRestart}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>deploy</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipDeploy}</skip>
                                <vmArguments>${scp.vmArguments}</vmArguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipRestart}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>rolling-update</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>rolling-update</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>${scp.skipRollingUpdate}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdkInstallPath>${scp.sdkInstallPath}</sdkInstallPath>
                        <skip>${scp.skipInstallSdk}</skip>

                        <application>${scp.app}</application>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</source>

                        <vmArguments>${scp.vmArguments}</vmArguments>
                        <size>${scp.vmSize}</size>
                        <minimumProcesses>${scp.vmMinProcesses}</minimumProcesses>
                        <maximumProcesses>${scp.vmMaxProcesses}</maximumProcesses>

                        <host>${scp.host}</host>
                        <account>${scp.account}</account>
                        <user>${scp.username}</user>
                        <password>${scp.password}</password>
                        <synchronous>true</synchronous>

                        <httpProxyHost>${proxy.host}</httpProxyHost>
                        <httpProxyPort>${proxy.port}</httpProxyPort>
                        <httpsProxyHost>${proxy.host}</httpsProxyHost>
                        <httpsProxyPort>${proxy.port}</httpsProxyPort>

                        <consoleCommand />
                        <consoleHttpProxyHost>${proxy.host}</consoleHttpProxyHost>
                        <consoleHttpProxyPort>${proxy.port}</consoleHttpProxyPort>
                        <consoleHttpsProxyHost>${proxy.host}</consoleHttpsProxyHost>
                        <consoleHttpsProxyPort>${proxy.port}</consoleHttpsProxyPort>

                        <dbsystem />
                        <dbSize />
                        <dbUser />
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Plugin for deployment to local runtime of SAP Cloud Platform Neo. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scp-neo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdkPlugin>neo-javaee7-wp-maven-plugin</sdkPlugin>
                        <sdkPluginVersion>${scp.sdkVersion}</sdkPluginVersion>
                        <sdkInstallPath>${scp.sdkInstallPath}</sdkInstallPath>
                        <sdkSymbolicLink>${scp.sdkSymbolicLink}</sdkSymbolicLink>
                        <sdkServerContentPath>${scp.sdkLocalServerContentPath}</sdkServerContentPath>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</source>
                        <proxyHost>${proxy.host}</proxyHost>
                        <proxyPort>${proxy.port}</proxyPort>
                        <httpNonProxyHosts>${non.proxy.hosts}</httpNonProxyHosts>
                        <destinations>
                            <destination>
                                <path>${scp.sdkErpEndpoint}</path>
                                <username>achacon</username>
                                <password>*******</password>
                                <url>http://crmdev:4431</url>
                            </destination>
                        </destinations>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>usage-analytics-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>usage-analytics</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipUsageAnalytics>false</skipUsageAnalytics>
                            <generateSalt>true</generateSalt>
                                <!--
                                Note: A random salt is auto-generated once the project is built for the first time.
                                Please keep the generated salt in the POM file, for example, when pushing to git.

                                To learn more, visit: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/10/23/usage-analytics-s4sdk/
                                -->
                            <salt>5d5e4e1e8a5f05d547fe8880f65173bda150a670f91f3657b970eaa9e7a4d392</salt>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <!--
        Profiles that are used to set the Neo SDK "neo" command extension ("neo.sh" or "neo.cmd")
        -->
        <profile>
            <id>windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>.bat</scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>unix</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>unix</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>.sh</scp.sdkNeoCmdExtension>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <!-- Profile setting properties for deploying to the local SAP CP runtime. -->
        <profile>
            <id>local-deploy</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>!scp.app</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.skipInstallSdk>true</scp.skipInstallSdk>
                <scp.skipDeploy>true</scp.skipDeploy>
                <scp.skipPutDestination>true</scp.skipPutDestination>
                <scp.skipRestart>true</scp.skipRestart>
                <scp.skipRollingUpdate>true</scp.skipRollingUpdate>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <!-- Profile setting properties for deploying a productive version to SAP CP. -->
        <profile>
            <id>scp-deploy</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>productive</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <scp.skipInstallSdk>false</scp.skipInstallSdk>
                <scp.skipDeploy>true</scp.skipDeploy>
                <scp.skipPutDestination>false</scp.skipPutDestination>
                <scp.skipRestart>true</scp.skipRestart>
                <scp.skipRollingUpdate>false</scp.skipRollingUpdate>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

This is my ErpQueryEndpoint file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1GzX.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the good question. The first thing I've noticed you're using an already quite outdated version of the SDK, the current one is `3.14.0`, you're on the `3.2.0` at the moment. We do a lot of fixes with every release and I would recommend
switching to the latest one in your dependencies. Take a look in our [release notes](https://help.sap.com/doc/6c02295dfa8f47cf9c08a19f2e172901/1.0/en-US/index.html)

In regards to Resilience, it's hard to tell exactly why the load test might fail because you use SDK on quite a low level by invoking an un-typed request builder that is not maintained by the SDK team. For Odata V2 `ODataCreateRequestImpl` is a dependency and not meant for direct consumption. We expose it only for edge cases and convenience.

A more reliable way to use SDK would be to generate a Virtual Data Model from your service definition first and then build typed requests. Those should be more
reliably implemented and easier to debug.

- Is it an option for you to generate the Virtual Data Model first and use the preferable way of building requests? [This tutorial covers the topic of the way SDK is intended to be used for the most use cases](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/s4sdk-odata-service-cloud-foundry.html)
- [Here is the tutorial covering basic Resilience setup](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/s4sdk-resilience.html)

I'll see if I can find more ideas about this case, in the meanwhile updating the SDK version and checking if you can use typed request builders mentioned in the tutorials above for CRUD would be a good idea.

If you have any additional details that might shed more light on this case, feel free to share them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Kovalyov. I updated the version of SAP Cloud SDK to 3.14.0, however, when trying to start the local SCP deployment, I get the following error: https://i.imgur.com/C1jAr3Y.png
https://i.imgur.com/TCaJcrL.png
I don't know if it helps but this is the directory structure of my project: https://i.imgur.com/cBBeK4k.png

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your response, Kovalyov. I updated to version 3.14.0 of SAP Cloud SDK as you  suggested, that was part of the solution to my problem.

After upgrading to version 3.14.0 of SAP Cloud SDK, I tried starting the local SCP deployment, however,  I got an error. The solution to the error was to eliminate the following dependency of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Additionally, it was necessary to replace the following instruction in my code:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> futureFirstStep = ResilienceDecorator.queueCallable(() ->
            executeAsyncCall(bpCreateRequest), conf);
```

With this instruction:

```
new Thread(() -> {
        some instruction;
    }).start();
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge and figuring things our @Aimee! The migration between versions is not every time easy indeed. We usually release a new SDK version every second week with multiple updates, fixes etc. I would recommend updating your dependencies from time to time. It will make sure you're not facing some breaking changes or dependency issues because of big version spread. Thanks again for posting your findings here!